# How to prevent Google (and others) from indexing the site under construction?

Tags: robots.txt, search-engine-indexing

Recently I faced with the situation that the wrong site pages (with wrong URLs, wrong content) was indexed by Google during the site developing.
Should I place robots.txt with

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And delete it after the site developing was finished?
Or I shouldn't bother with it at all?

Comment: is there any content? have you not got a development environment?

Comment: Yes, @Liam there is some content. The question not related to the project I described above, I'm talking about the right site development strategy in general.

Comment: have you looked at adding a 503 error message? And I also don't think the duplicate is relevant to this post

Comment: @LiamSorsby No I didn't. Should I?

Comment: well thats upto you however i would if you create a subdomain/local environment and create a development environment and test on this leaving your site untouched until the app/site has been finished and tested

Comment: @Liam I'm not actually get your idea but I don't believe that it is even possible to explain within a comment scope :) Could you point me to the right reading regarding the subject? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314088/setting-up-a-development-server or for windows server environment use xampp or look at the answer of the duplicate for an idea. Also take a look at the second answer that is rather explanitory